# Mongoos Add dynamic columns Error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

> I want to add dynamic columns in my document but when add new column
>   it display error, I m using mongoDB 3.4

```
router.post('/get-personal-information', function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
Employee.update({_id : req.body._id},{$set:{'name1' : 'dsadas'}}, {upsert:true}, function(err, doc){
    if (err) return res.send(500, { error: err });
    return res.send(doc);
});
});
```

> Error Message ::

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "MongoError",
    "message": "'$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$set: {<field>: ...}}",
    "driver": true,
    "index": 0,
    "code": 9,
    "errmsg": "'$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$set: {<field>: ...}}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution

> Use {strict: false} to modify the columns or make any type of
>   operation on columns

```
router.post('/get-personal-information', function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
Employee.update({_id : req.body._id},{$set:{'name1' : 'dsadas'}}, {strict:false}, function(err, doc){
    if (err) return res.send(500, { error: err });
    return res.send(doc);
});
});
```